# Issue running tensorflow with java

Tags: java, tensorflow

I am having some issues running tensorflow with java. I am using CUDA 8 with CuDNN 6.

I tried following the quickstart instructions located here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java and get the following error message when I attempt to run the example java program:

```
java -cp libtensorflow-1.4.0.jar:. -Djava.library.path=./jni HelloTF

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: linux, architecture: x86_64. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source). Additional information on attempts to find the native library can be obtained by adding org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1 to the system properties of the JVM.
    at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:75)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:66)
    at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:70)
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:258)
    at HelloTF.main(HelloTF.java:8)
```

The jni directory contains the following:

> - libtensorflow_framework.so
> - libtensorflow_jni.so
> - LICENSE

I then tried installing the binaries from source as suggested here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/README.md

This is the output from setting: `org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1`

```
org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary: tryLoadLibraryFailed: /path/to/jni/libtensorflow_jni.so: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary: jniResourceName: org/tensorflow/native/linux-x86_64/libtensorflow_jni.so
org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary: frameworkResourceName: org/tensorflow/native/linux-x86_64/libtensorflow_framework.so
```

But I still get the same error message when I try and run the example Java program.

What am I doing wrong??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: linux, architecture: x86_64.

is clearly stating that the library is not visible to your software.

To make it available to the Java class, try doing like that (in the same shell obviously):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/the/absolute/path/to/your/library
java -cp libtensorflow-1.4.0.jar:. -Djava.library.path=./jni HelloTF
```

also ensure you're running the java command from the same directory which contains the `/jni` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried adding export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/tensorflow but the problem still persists. I have added the debug output to the question.

Comment: avoid putting the file in the path :)

Comment: Aah I was confused as to which library I needed to add! I added export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/cuda and that did the trick! Although I should have already done that when I installed cuda earlier today.

Comment: I'm new to tensorflow and started with the Java maven approach. I hoped I didn't need to install TensorFlow itself. After getting the same error as above, I concluded that I need to install TF anyway. Am I right?

Comment: @hsmit I've tried and it works seamlessly. Just follow [the guidelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java#example) properly (and consider upvoting :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios if I follow the instructions I get an error: `ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project java-tensorflow: An exception occured while executing the Java class. C:\Users\
Me\AppData\Local\Temp\tensorflow_native_libraries-1511797444978-0\tensorflow_jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @hsmit can you zip your project (which should consist of just the files from the example in the guidelines) and put it on google drive or something, so we can see what's the problem? Otherwise, consider opening a new answer and posting everything there

Answer (score 0):

For those landing here and facing the same issue.

You are probably trying to run your program from eclipse. Then, you have to go to Run configurations > Arguments and pass this arguments:

- Program arguments -> models/
                   images/example-400x288.jpg
- VM Arguments -> -Djava.library.path=./jni

like in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When people (like myself) come from python to java world, everything is strange! here is how I solved my problem regarding all linking errors:
I assumed you already have simple hello Tensorflow project, explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java)

1. [Download](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java#download) and copy tensorflow JNI files to :/usr/lib/tensorflow
2. [Download](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java#download) and copy desired version of tensorflow Lib jar file to: /usr/lib/tensorflow

   Compile with java
3. Compile java file

```sh
javac -cp /usr/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow-1.14.0.jar HelloTensorFlow.java
```

4. run java file:

```sh
java -cp /usr/lib/tensorflow/libtensorflow-1.14.0.jar:. -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/tensorflow/ HelloTensorFlow
```

use MAVEN

1. First we should export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/tensorflow
```

2. Then run maven build command:

```sh
mvn -q compile exec:java
```

I hope it helps you